# How to create a channel which was not in the initial channelconfig during the network creation?

Tags: hyperledger-fabric, channel

I am using Hyperledger Fabric for permissioned Blockchain Network. I created one channel with 2 organizations. Now the network is up and running. Now I want to create another new channel which was not defined in the initial configuration. Now what is the process of creating such new channel?

Comment: sorry, I am simply commenting here so I get a notification if anyone answers this. From what I know, you can use `fabric-client` API to add new channels without using bash scripts. So these should be able to add channels dynamically. I am in the process of testing it out, will take a few days. If no one answers and I manage, will post the code here

Comment: What SDK are you using? There is a fairly detailed tutorial here for Node: https://fabric-sdk-node.github.io/release-1.4/tutorial-channel-create.html

Comment: https://fabrictestdocs.readthedocs.io/en/latest/asset_cli.html#manually-create-and-join-peers-to-a-new-channel